# Custom Context for sticky broadcasts with Robolectric

Tags: android, robolectric

I would like to test my `BroadcastReceiver`, which depends on sticky broadcasts, with Robolectric. By default Robolectric does not support sticky broadcasts so I created my custom `Context` to get sticky broadcasts working like this:

```
public class MyContext extends MockContext {

    public MyContext() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public Intent registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter) {
        if(receiver == null) { // A sticky broadcast was requested
            Intent request = new Intent();
            String action = filter.getAction(0);

            if(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED.equals(action)) {
                request.putExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, 1);
            } else if(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG.equals(action)) {
                request.putExtra("state", 1); 
            }

            return request;
        }

        return super.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }
}
```

My problem is that I have to use `RuntimeEnvironment.application.getApplicationContext` to get a valid `Context` object (I tried to simply call the constructor of my custom `Context` but that does not work). So how can I get a valid instance of my custom `Context` or isn't that possible with robolectric?

**EDIT**: Here is the code from my test and my BroadcastReceiver:

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    context = RuntimeEnvironment.application.getApplicationContext();
    receiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver(); // Create Receiver
}

@After
public void finish() {
    context.unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}

@Test
public void validateUsbChargingChange() {
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED");
    context.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

    // Simmulate SocketCharging by sending the corresponding Intent
    Intent chargingChange = new Intent("android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED");
    RuntimeEnvironment.application.sendBroadcast(chargingChange);

    validatePreferences();
}
```

**BroadcastReceiver:**

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    IntentFilter iFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    Intent chargingIntent = appContext.registerReceiver(null, iFilter); // sticky
    int pluggedState = chargingIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);

    boolean usbCharge = (pluggedState == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB);
    if(usbCharge) {  /* Write values to preferences */  }
}
```

Comment: What version of Robolectric are you using? Looking in ShadowApplication, I see code that really looks like it wants to handle sticky intents.

https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blame/master/robolectric-shadows/shadows-core/src/main/java/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowApplication.java#L552

Comment: Oh right... I'm using Robolectric version 3.3.1

Comment: How does your test look like?

Answer (score 0):

you can explicitly sendStickBroadcast in you test class constructor, just like below

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class BatterySettingActivityTest {
    {
        ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext().sendStickyBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED).putExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 75).putExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, 0));
    }

    @Rule
    public ActivityScenarioRule<BatterySettingActivity> activityScenarioRule = new ActivityScenarioRule<>(BatterySettingActivity.class);


    @Test
    public void testStickBroadcast() {
        activityScenarioRule.getScenario().onActivity(activity -> {
            System.out.println("intentForStickyBroadcast=" + activity.registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED)));
        });
    }
}
```